# What does "Pearl-Harbor meets Stalingrad" mean?

Tags: meaning

I came across this sentence while I was reading a book named "[LOSING MILITARY SUPREMACY](https://books.google.com/books?id=ye6oDwAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&printsec=frontcover&pg=PT60&dq=Putin%E2%80%99s+message+was+clear:+%E2%80%9CYou+didn%E2%80%99t+listen+to+us+then,+you+will+listen+to+us+now%E2%80%9D.+After+that+he+proceeded+with+what+can+only+be+described+as+a+military-technological+Pearl-Harbormeets-Stalingrad&hl=en&source=gb_mobile_entity)" from Andrei Martyanov:

> After that he proceeded with what can only be described as a military-technological Pearl-Harbor meets Stalingrad.

Comment: Are you familiar with the construction [**X meets Y**](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/JustForFun/XMeetsY)?  It means, roughly, "something like a combination of X and Y".

Comment: Moreover are you familiar with the historical "Attack on Pearl Harbour" and the "Battle of Stalingrad"?

Comment: Not with the Stalingrad one

Answer (score 2):

When we use the expression 'A is B meets C' we are saying that the first thing mentioned has the notable qualities of the second and third things. The author is saying that the event described is bad for America, like Pearl Harbor, and good for Russia, like the battle of Stalingrad. Good, that is, if you discount the casualties (we are talking about Putin's Russia here).

1. Pearl Harbor (not 'Pearl-Harbor' as in the text) was a shock and a turning point for the USA; it ended any remnants of isolationism and forced her to become involved in a global war.
2. Stalingrad was a turning point for the Soviet Union - it marked the start of Germany's decline to defeat.  Stalingrad not only blunted the German ability to wage war, but broke it almost completely. It was the most defining and important moment in the war on the Eastern Front and arguably the entire war. The scope of the German loss meant that Germany would never be able to recover any kind of force capable of pushing the Soviets back, who were now poised to retake all of their lost territory and push on to Berlin.

So the significance of the event (development of the X-101 and 3M14 missiles), says the author, is danger and shock for the USA combined with strategically increased power for Russia. A shift in the global balance of military power between the USA and Russia.

Comment: This explanation is very good in this context! Note how this particular metaphorical explanation (shock for the USA, power increase for Russia) only applies in this particular context. Other people could use the two battles to mean very different things. Maybe they talk about a military disaster and use "Pearl Harbor meets Stalingrad" to convey the devastation of that loss by combining two devastating losses from WW2.

Comment: @xyldke - Pearl Harbor was not terminal for America, but Stalingrad was the start of Germany's defeat. One could view Pearl Harbor as a foolish attack by an over-confident and misguided Japan. Start a war with America and you tend to lose.

Comment: You could equally see 'Pearl Harbor meets Stalingrad' as a combination of a wake-up call for America and a disaster for Russia.

Answer (score 0):

Pearl Harbor was a lightning-quick surprise attack that nearly destroyed the American Pacific fleet. Stalingrad was a protracted siege of Stalingrad by the German Army during World War II. By itself the sentence does not make sense to me. I imagine the author wrote more to explain the connection he sees between these two rather different military events.

Answer (score -1):

From a [review](https://www.scoop.co.nz/stories/HL2001/S00005/avoidable-nuclear-war.htm) of the book quoted:

> The book has all the appearance of never having been proofread and
> thus of having been published in great haste. Undue haste might call
> into question some of the many facts that fill its pages. There are
> expressions of anger at America having placed humanity in such nuclear
> jeopardy and contempt for the incompetence, greed and ignorance of the
> US elite that has led them to the current existential crisis. Again,
> this display of emotion by the author, though understandable and
> almost certainly justified, makes Martyanov appear so partisan that
> one is bound to look for corroboration elsewhere.